# XML won't take style format which is loaded in IIS

Tags: xml, xslt, iis, virtual-directory

I have one XML file and one xsl file to format XML. When I set the "href=c:\local\2.xsl" then it works correctly.

But I need to place that same xsl file on IIS virtual directory and put the reference path of that, like "href='http://someIP/style/2.xsl'"

But when I'm doing that, format won't apply correctly.

Could anyone please suggest why It is not working from IIS.

Comment: Where do you load the XML from, also over HTTP from the same local server? Which browser do you use, have you opened developer tools with F12 and checked the error console on any error messages in the error or network tab to see what goes wrong?

Comment: Hi Martin, 

Thanks for the response. I could get below details. Please have a look.

XML file a location at my local path. (e.g. at Desktop),
IIS server is also configured at my local machine,
I use iExplorer 11 to open XML,

When I use F12 (Developer tool), I see an error like - "Request for cross-domain XSLT was denied.".

Comment: As the error message indicates, the browser, for security reasons, does not allow a stylesheet loaded from on origin (e.g. your file system) to load an XSLT stylesheet from another origin (e.g. a web server). So you might need to ensure that both files are loaded either from the local file system or from the local web server. Another option might be to check whether IE has some configuration to lower the security restrictions for localhost.

Comment: Hi Martin,

Thanks for your inputs, I just added my xsl file URL into trusted sites and it started working. This is resolved.